# Setting Pulldown on the PMOD Pins (Nexys A7)

Tags: fpga, verilog, keypad

Ive created a keypad scanning project with Verilog. The waveform works great! But it did not work in practice. Through troubleshooting I found that it will work if I add external pulldown resistors to the pins im using as inputs. Ive read that its possible within Verilog to set a pin to pulldown. However im not finding great information on how to implement it. Through docs it looks like it should be done by the line `set_property PULLDOWN TRUE [get_ports outputport]`, however my xdc file seems to be formatted different and I have been unable to figure it out. So, how do I set PMOD pins to pulldown with my XDC file?
XDC PMOD lines:

```
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { column[1] }]; #IO_L16N_T2_A27_15 Sch=ja[7]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { column[2] }]; #IO_L16P_T2_A28_15 Sch=ja[8]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { column[3] }]; #IO_L22N_T3_A16_15 Sch=ja[9]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { column[4] }]; #IO_L22P_T3_A17_15 Sch=ja[10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'PULLDOWN' attribute/property is deprecated. You can do it using 'PULLTYPE' attribute instead in Vivado. Either apply this attribute in your RTL code, or in the XDC constraint file. Writing in the XDC file makes the RTL more portable. You can write a separate line in XDC for that port:

> set_property PULLTYPE {PULLDOWN} [get_ports <port_name>]

Refer [Page 319 of this Vivado Document](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug912-vivado-properties.pdf) for more details.